# Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, Array given in (line 120 of display_ket.module

Tags: php, arrays, drupal-7

can someone help me to resolve this problem I've try any solution but still getting error, for firts time I using split date then i use explode because i received error and using php 5.6 .. $par is input

> Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
>   konversitgl()

My Code .

```
function konversitgl($par){
 $elemen=explode("-",$par); // this line 120
 return $elemen[2].'/'.$elemen[1].'/'.$elemen[0];
 }
function balikin_tgl($par){
$elemen=explode("/",$par );
return $elemen[2].'-'.$elemen[1].'-'.$elemen[0];
}
function tglInd($par){
  $elemen=explode("-",$par );
  $var=milih_bulan();
  return number_format($elemen[2]).' '.$var[$elemen[1]].' '.$elemen[0];
}
function tglformat($par){
  $elemen=explode("/",$par );
  return $elemen[2].'-'.$elemen[1].'-'.$elemen[0];
}

function get_triwulan($bln){
  if ($bln<=3){
    $n = 1;
  } elseif ($bln<=6){
    $n = 2;
  } elseif ($bln<=9){
    $n = 3;
  } else { 
    $n = 4;
  }  
  return $n;
}

function valid_tanggal($tgl_cek){
  global $user;
  $panjang = strlen($tgl_cek);
  //if (!ereg ("([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{4})", $tgl_cek)){
  if (!preg_match ("/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})/", $tgl_cek)){
      $hasil_cek = false;
  }else{
      $tahun = substr($tgl_cek,-4);
      $tgl = substr($tgl_cek,0,2);
      $bulan   = substr($tgl_cek,3,2);
      if($bulan>12){
         $hasil_cek = false;
      }else if($tgl>31){
           $hasil_cek = false;
      }else{
        if($bulan==02){
           if($tgl>29){
            $hasil_cek = false;
           }else{
            $hasil_cek = true;
           }
        }else{
           $hasil_cek = true;
        }
      }
  }
  return $hasil_cek;
}
             db_set_active('default');
      $xx = date('Y-m-d');
      $yy = substr($xx,0,4);
      $mm = substr($xx,5,2);
      $dd = substr($xx,8,2);   
      if($awal==NULL){
        $awal  = $yy."-".$mm."-01";
      }
      if($akhir==NULL){
        $akhir  = $yy."-".$mm."-".$dd;
      }
```

Comment: what is $par ? show more code

Comment: For `explode` the second parameter must be an string which you need to convert to array. You are passing an array to explode.

Comment: it's function parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you function to this.

```
function konversitgl($par)
{
    if(is_string($par))
    {
        $elemen = explode("-", $par); // this line 120
        return $elemen[2] . '/' . $elemen[1] . '/' . $elemen[0];
    }
}
```